# handle multiple ForeinKeys in one field _ Django

Tags: django, django-models

suppose we have a Model A that has relations ForeinKey to Model B.

```
class B(models.Model):
.....

class A(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeinKey(B)
```

how can I have an instance of A model that has dozens of **foo** ? and a proper solution I need for that. is that possible?
I think this is dummm if we made many foo fields. so is it possible in django to handle this type of problems?

Comment: Have a look at [many-to-many fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: it works fine with many to many . but this is only answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is slightly unclear, but I will try to answer both cases that came to my mind.

## If every assignment of `B` to `A` should have different purpose (and there is limited amount of them)

This may be the case if for example `B` represents person and `A` represents book. And now you want to have for example fields for: author of the book, publisher of the book, translator of the book etc. In that case, you should just create multiple foreign keys. But there is a catch... Django is creating by default virtual field in model that you're referencing to, so you can traverse back your relation. This field is named after class, you're referencing the model from, and in this example it is named `a_set`. Unfortunately, for every relation, this field is named exactly the same, so they will clash.

Solution for that issue is to either specify explicitly name of that virtual field:

```
class B(models.Model):
.....

class A(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeinKey(B, related_name='books_written')
    publisher = models.ForeinKey(B, related_name='books_published')
    translator = models.ForeinKey(B, related_name='books_translated')
```

or you can just disable those reverse fields:

```
class B(models.Model):
.....

class A(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeinKey(B, related_name='+')
    publisher = models.ForeinKey(B, related_name='+')
    translator = models.ForeinKey(B, related_name='+')
```

## If every assignment of `B` to `A` should have (roughly) the same purpose or you cannot specify how much of them will be there.

This can happen if for example, as in previous case, `A` represents book, and `B` represents person and all you want to do is to assign multiple authors to one book. In this case, you should create many-to-many relation between those two models. Django is offering [`ManyToMany`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) field for that purpose and its usage is very simple:

```
class B(models.Model):
.....

class A(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(B)
```

If for any reason you want to have multiple many-to-many relations between those two models, problem with clashing virtual reverse relation fields also occurs, as in first case. Fix for that is equivalent.

Also, instead of using `ManyToManyField` to create that relation, you can craft it by yourself, by creating 3rd model that will just have foreign keys to both of them (that's what Django is doing in background when you use that field). You can even register that model using `ManyToManyField` using `through` parameter of that field to have direct relation and reverse relation fields for ease of use.