# Django models save 2 Foreinkeys to same Model

Tags: django-models, foreign-keys

Following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54417190/handle-multiple-foreinkeys-in-one-field-django) and documentation, somehow it still can't save an Object with 2 Foreinkeys.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) #User.photo_set.all() returns all Photo objects of the photo
    photoURL = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    secondPhoto = models.OneToOneField('self', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class Clash(models.Model):
    win_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo,on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="wins", null=True)
    loss_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo,on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="losses", null=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=False) #we will filter those out for user quality calculations
```

[image]

Comment: You can, but you should really use named parameters, like `Clash(win_photo=p[0].pk, loss_photo=p[1].pk)`.

Comment: Dude you are a boss, it was as simple as that. And now I can pass Photo objects instead of pk's